# Wave background on top and bottom of a section

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a section FAQ, which I would like a top section to have top wave background and bottom section also to have a wave background

I would like to have something like this
[image]

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
<section id="faq">
  <div id="details">
  </div>
</section>
```

css

```
#faq{
  background-image: url("wave-top.svg")
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is two images I have for background

Top wave
[image]

Bottom wave

[image]

What do I need to do to get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple background and adjust the `background-size`/`background-position`:

```css
.box {
  padding:11% 0; /* The padding is the area for the shapes, adjust it based on the ratio of the shape*/
  height:100px; /* to illustrate the space for the content */
  background:
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG3Vb.png) top   /100% auto,
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSEyE.png) bottom/100% auto,
    linear-gradient(#387dff,#387dff) content-box; /* Color between the shapes only on the content and not the padding*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: How can I make it responsive?

Comment: @user9964622 it's already reponsive beause I am using percetange value for padding. and the height will increase depeding on the content (I used a fixed value here to illustrate but you can remove it and have the content define the height)

Comment: Here is my dev I am testing online check it out, it's not responsive :  or maybe there is something wrong with my code : https://videommerce.com/videommerce-pricing/

Comment: @user9964622 you are overriding the padding I am setting with another rule, try `padding:11% 0 !important`

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving the desired result is via pseudo elements.
The below code snippet should be a good start

```css
#faq {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 40px 0; /* make the padding the same as the height of the pseudo elements*/
}

#faq:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG3Vb.png');
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; /*make the height the same as the height of the background image size*/
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#faq:after {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSEyE.png');
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; /*make the height the same as the height of the background image size*/
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#details-wrapper {
  background-color: #387dff;
  width: 100%
}

#details {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section id="faq">
  <div id="details-wrapper">
    <div id="details">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

**Edit**

As per Temani Afif's suggestion I've updated the code snippet to use `background-size: 100% 100%;` as opposed to `background-size: 100% 40px;` thereby removing another variable to remember to adjust

Comment: you can simplify the background-size using `100% 100%` so by default it will get the height specified and you remove one parametre

Comment: is this responsive?

Comment: @user9964622 yes it is